# melt function applied to json input replaces some values with factors

Tags: r, reshape2, rjson

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "observations": [
    {
      "type": "ob_type_1",
      "data": {
        "dynamic": {
          "sensor": [
            {
              "timestamp": 552625694285098,
              "a": 1.4921862,
              "b": 8.613739
            },
            {
              "timestamp": 552625699285098,
              "a": 0.6907272,
              "b": 7.6243353
            }
          ]
        },
        "static": {
          "class1": "abc",
          "class2": "xyz"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I import it using rjson:

```
library(rjson)
raw_json <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
```

To reproduce please use:

```
raw_json <-    structure(list(observations = list(structure(list(type = "ob_type_1", 
        data = structure(list(dynamic = structure(list(sensor = list(
            structure(list(timestamp = 552625694285098, a = 1.4921862, 
                b = 8.613739), .Names = c("timestamp", "a", "b")), 
            structure(list(timestamp = 552625699285098, a = 0.6907272, 
                b = 7.6243353), .Names = c("timestamp", "a", "b")))), .Names = "sensor"), 
            static = structure(list(class1 = "abc", class2 = "xyz"), .Names = c("class1", 
            "class2"))), .Names = c("dynamic", "static"))), .Names = c("type", 
    "data")))), .Names = "observations")
```

I then melt it using reshape2:

```
library(reshape2)    
reshape_json <- melt(raw_json)
```

The value column however displays '1' and '2' for 'class1' and 'class2'. I would like these to be 'abc' and 'xyz'. How can I achieve this? I've experimented with jsonlite in the past but struggled to get the correct output when my json file had nested arrays.

```
            value        L7 L6     L5      L4   L3 L2           L1
1       ob_type_1      <NA> NA   <NA>    <NA> type  1 observations
2 552625694285098 timestamp  1 sensor dynamic data  1 observations
3       1.4921862         a  1 sensor dynamic data  1 observations
4        8.613739         b  1 sensor dynamic data  1 observations
5 552625699285098 timestamp  2 sensor dynamic data  1 observations
6       0.6907272         a  2 sensor dynamic data  1 observations
7       7.6243353         b  2 sensor dynamic data  1 observations
8               1      <NA> NA class1  static data  1 observations
9               2      <NA> NA class2  static data  1 observations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```